# How can I disable gnome-shell's notification area?

Tags: 11.10, ati, gnome, notification-area

I want to disable the notification area in gnome-shell because it causes alot of graphical glitches for my computer. I use tint2 for my system tray. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what side effects, if any, this will have, but here's one way to do it:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/main.js
```

Find the following line (217 for me):

```
notificationDaemon = new NotificationDaemon.NotificationDaemon();
```

Comment it out:

```
//notificationDaemon = new NotificationDaemon.NotificationDaemon();
```

Save the file, press Alt-F2 and enter `r` to reload GNOME Shell. The tray should now be gone

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gnome 3.2 then you might find something useful at http://extensions.gnome.org

such as

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/99/evial-status-icon-forerver/