# How to disable the Mount notification in Gnome 3.4?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, notification

How to disable those annoying notifications when you plug a new disk in, or connect to a network and so on....

I know that if I add a device to a mount script they will be mounted on boot thus not showing me the notification, which I did for my hard drives, but it doesn't help with all those flash disks I have... I can't add them all that would be silly.

I looked at:

[How can I disable gnome-shell's notification area?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73347/how-can-i-disable-gnome-shells-notification-area)

... but they didn't help, since the code was different

I also looked at configuration editor, but I think it can only disable auto-mount when inserted, it doesn't disable notification...

Comment: Yeah, or use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling autorun-never true`